# SQLite Delete 10000 rows from table

Tags: sql, sqlite

My SQLite Database have 50000 rows of record. I want to delete 10000 rows of records. However below code having Syntax error.

```
DELETE FROM Messages LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: What dialect of SQL are you using?

Comment: THanks, it is SQLite. Added in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rowid with some tweak as you want to delete 10000 records without any order as follows:

```
delete from your_table
where rowid IN (select rowid from your_table limit 10000)
```

Comment: thanks this works 
`DELETE FROM Messages WHERE id in(SELECT id FROM Messages LIMIT 10000)`